# overcome error messages from appearing when failing because of slow internet in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, connection-timeout

overcome error messages from appearing when failing because of slow internet in CodeIgniter,

if the email failed to send because internet time out show message or redirect so that no error messages. Thanks

```
function sent_email_contact_admin($data){
    $CI=& get_instance();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'rental.alternet@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '******';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $data = array (
        'nama' => $data['nama'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
            'message' => $data['message']

    );

    $data['base_url'] = base_url();
    $message = $CI->load->view('layout/email_template_contact_admin', $data, true); 
    $CI->load->library('email', $config);
    $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $CI->email->from('rental.alternet@gmail.com');
    $CI->email->to('rental.alternet@gmail.com');
    $CI->email->reply_to($data['email']);
    $CI->email->subject("Info Contact Alternet");
    $CI->email->message($message);

    $CI->email->send();



}
```

Comment: Perhaps wrapping in a try catch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if ( ! $CI->email->send())
    {
            // Generate error
    }
  else
   {
        //redirect
   }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and explain why this would work.